# You do not have any instances in this region

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have created EC2 instance in the my office PC. It was successfully and I used it well. But when I logged to the AWS console from my home laptom - no one instance exist there and I have the error **You do not have any instances in this region**. I try to search instance information in other regions but do not found any.

[image]

How I can found my created instance or list all instances independently of region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick way would be to use combination of [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2.html), [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and a simple Bash for loop to iterate through each region and list the instances. Be sure to set your credentials before running

```
for region in `aws ec2 describe-regions | jq .Regions\[\].RegionName -r`
do
    echo -e "\tRegion: ${region}"
    aws ec2 describe-instances --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].{InstanceID:InstanceId}" --output=table --region ${region}
done
```

---

You can copy post the code in your Linux shell, or run them in [AWS CloudShell](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudshell/) which gives you an authenticated shell with aws cli preinstalled

Comment: It is cool to use a cli in aws, but how I can open this page? I mean aws.amazon.com/cli. I get to this url - abd the service propose me sigin in to account. I joined and get to the home page.Than I again go to the /cli url - and again I need to sign in.

Comment: you install the cli on your local system, the links are available on the page linked. I updated the link to another doc to be clear.

Comment: So, I need to create bash/bat script with this loop and execute it in the local machine? How do I need to set credentials before running?

Comment: yes, you need to run it on local or even better copy+paste them in cloudshell. You might need to install jq